# Redhat subscription issue

Tags: redhat, rhel7, openshift-enterprise

Hi I am installation openshift 3.3 , 30 days trial version on RHEL 7.3, have registered the system using subscription-manager . I was able to attach pool id but suddenly its giving this "No available subscription pools to list" though in redhat portal I can see my subscription is still active. Any idea why this happens? I have faced this issue several time with redhat subscriptions

FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "No OpenShift version               available, please ensure your systems are fully registered and have access to appropriate yum repositories."}

any help?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue for OpenShift 3.4 using the following command on all hosts in the cluster:

`atomic-openshift-excluder unexclude`

"The ***-excluder** packages add entries to the exclude directive in the host’s */etc/yum.conf* file when installed. Run the following command on each host to remove the **atomic-openshift** packages from the list for the duration of the installation." See documentation [here](http://red.ht/2jAZ2b6).